# Embed SVG into HTML5 SVG without rasterization

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I used the **image** tag to use a SVG File as content inside a HTML5 **svg** tag.

This works in Chromium, but not in Firefox.

As i added some zooming functionality I realized that Chrome converts the SVG image into a raster image. Is there a way to change the behavior of the **image** tag or any other SVG element I could use for including a SVG file without touching its internal data.

**EDIT:**
 Actually I am writing a Framework to do interactive animated stuff in a **svg** element. It is important for this purpose that i can access the loaded data via the **use** tag.
Here some of the Source Code so you can see what this is about:

```
function createSVG( para ){
     if ( ! para["shape"] ) return undefined;
     var newElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",para["shape"]);
      for ( var p in para ) {
                      if ( p == "xlink:href" ) newElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", p, para[p] );
                      else if ( p != "shape") newElement.setAttribute( p, para[p] );
      }
      return newElement
}

function defineSVG( para ){
     var data = createSVG( para );
     $(myDefs).append(data); // myDefs is the <defs> element used to store shapes etc.
}

function loadImageSVG( id, file, width, height ) { 
      defineSVG({ 
                "shape": "image", 
                "id" : id, 
                "xlink:href" : file, 
                "width" : width, 
                "height" : height, 
                "transform" : translate( - (width / 2), - (height / 2) ) // center image for later translation
       });     
}  
function useSVG( id, show ) {
                var data = createSVG({
                      "shape" : "use",
                        "id" : id,
                        "xlink:href": "#" + show,
                        "transform": ""
               })
              $(myContent).append( data ); // myContent is the <g> where i store <use> for all visible
              return data;
 }
 /* load SVG file smiley.svg and give id smile */
 loadImageSVG( "smile", "smiley.svg", 20, 20 ) 
 /* draw a 5 x 5 grid of smilies */ 
 for (var i = 0; i < 25; ++ i) {
        var turtle = useSVG( "turtle" + i, "smile" ); 
        turtle.setAttribute( "transform", "translate( " + (100 * (i / 5) ) + ", " + (100 * (i % 5  )  )  + " )" )                                  
   }
```

Comment: You could use the `<svg>` tag?  Why is it not working in Firefox?  It should work.  Please post your code or a link to your page.

Comment: Wich attribute of <svg> can be used to specify a external Resource?

Comment: Why do you need to specify an external resource?  Just stick the SVG directly in the DOM.

Comment: thought about that. this might cause other problems like making sure that all ids are still unique etc. should be no problem, just more work. So I wanted to check if there is an easy way, i might have missed in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the `object` tag: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Web-Use.html#Web-Use-Object

Also note [there's a bug in WebKit with SVG scaling](http://noahsarchive.net/noahsarchive/_design/sofa/_list/post/post-page?startkey=%5B%22JavaScript-Fix-for-WebKit-SVG-Scaling-Problem%22%5D).